# Realm db returns data in one activity and not in other

Tags: android, database, realm

I am making a test app to store sample records in realm database. I can access the data inside the first activity (MainActivity) but not in second (DisplayActivity). I just started using realmdb and don't know much about it. Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how it can be fixed? 
Code of the activities is given below.

first activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_display);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DisplayActivity.class));

        }
    });

    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmConfiguration configuration  =  new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("students")
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();

    Realm.deleteRealm(configuration);
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);

    realm.beginTransaction();
    StudentsModel st1 = realm.createObject(StudentsModel.class,UUID.randomUUID().toString());


    st1.setName("Wassauf");
    realm.commitTransaction();

    String resultstext = "";


    RealmResults<StudentsModel> resultsw = realm.where(StudentsModel.class).findAll();
    for (StudentsModel student: resultsw){

        resultstext+=student.getName().toString()  + student.getId() + "\n";

    }

    Toast.makeText(this, resultstext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Second Activity

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RealmResults<StudentsModel>  results ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    //Realm.init(getApplicationContext());


    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    String resulttext="";

    RealmResults<StudentsModel> resultsw = realm.where(StudentsModel.class).findAll();
    for (StudentsModel student: resultsw){

        resulttext+=student.getName() + student.getId() + "\n";

    }


    Toast.makeText(this, resulttext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}


}
```

Comment: Consider not deleting your database in `onCreate` and use `initialData(` instead

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more and tell what to add or replace..

Comment: Remove `Realm.deleteRealm(configuration);` and add `initialData(new Realm.Transaction() { ...` to add that item you are adding in that random transaction in onCreate